# Converting Excel to Txt in Batch without defining the path

Tags: vba, excel

I've spent some time in developing these functions, but i want to make it more convenient because i have roughly 50++ of excel workbook in one folder. My codes is not suitable for 50++ of excel workbook. I need some guides on how to do it in bulk without declaring all those path and put it in the Sub Combineheader() as shown in below. Can anyone enlighten me with this part? I do have limited skills for excel VBA and still learning. Hopefully i can make this thread useful to other as well. Thank you.

```
Sub Combineheader() 
/* The two subs below are having different path location for the output*/
/* if i have 50++ path location, i will be copy and paste for 50++ times */
CreateEJV1
CreateEJV2
End Sub

Sub CreateEJV1()
Dim myFfile As String

myFfile = "C:\Summary e-jv\AJSB\1.SAL-E-MTH.xlsx"

Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFfile

DatFile1Name = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\Testing1.txt"
Open DatFile1Name For Output As #2 'create csv file


vRow = 2
While Cells(vRow, 1).Value <> ""
 field1 = Cells(vRow, 1).Value
 field2 = Cells(vRow, 2).Value
 field3 = Cells(vRow, 3).Value
 field4 = Cells(vRow, 4).Value
 field5 = Cells(vRow, 5).Value
 field6 = Cells(vRow, 6).Value

Dim str As String  /* all of my workbooks are having the same format */ 

str = ""
str = field1 & "  " & field2 & "  " & field3 & "  " & field4 & "  " & field5 & "  " & field6


Print #2, str
vRow = vRow + 1

Wend

If IsEmpty(Range("A2").Value) = True Then
  Msg = "Error # " & Err.Number & " was generated by E-JV Excel Macro" _
     & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & "THERE ARE Details found " & Err.Description
MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End If
Close #2

ActiveWorkbook.Close

MsgBox ("File TESTING1.TXT created")

End Sub


Sub CreateEJV2()
Dim myFfile As String

myFfile = "C:\Summary e-jv\AJSB\2.IA-E-SAL.xlsx"

Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFfile

DatFile1Name = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\Testing2.txt"
Open DatFile1Name For Output As #2 'create csv file


vRow = 2
While Cells(vRow, 1).Value <> ""
 field1 = Cells(vRow, 1).Value
 field2 = Cells(vRow, 2).Value
 field3 = Cells(vRow, 3).Value
 field4 = Cells(vRow, 4).Value
 field5 = Cells(vRow, 5).Value
 field6 = Cells(vRow, 6).Value



Dim str As String   /* all of my workbooks are having the same format */ 

str = ""
str = field1 & "  " & field2 & "  " & field3 & "  " & field4 & "  " & field5 & "  " & field6



Print #2, str
vRow = vRow + 1


Wend

If IsEmpty(Range("A2").Value) = True Then
  Msg = "Error # " & Err.Number & " was generated by E-JV Excel Macro" _
     & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & "THERE ARE Details found " & Err.Description
 MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
 End If
Close #2

ActiveWorkbook.Close

MsgBox ("File TESTING2.TXT created")

End Sub
```

Comment: You only need a single sub which has two parameters - one for the source file path and one for the destination path.

Comment: @tim Williams source file path for the 50+ workbook and 50 destination path?

Comment: when you have your one sub you can call it as many times as you need, passing in the pairs of filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I mean - add two parameters to the sub which reads/writes the files, and call it with different file names:

```
Sub Combineheader()

    CreateEJ "C:\Summary e-jv\AJSB\1.SAL-E-MTH.xlsx", _
             ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Testing1.txt"

    CreateEJ "C:\Summary e-jv\AJSB\2.IA-E-SAL.xlsx", _
             ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Testing2.txt"
    'etc...

End Sub

Sub CreateEJ(srcFile As String, destFile As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, rw As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=srcFile)
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set rw = sht.Rows(2) '<< start on row2

    If rw.Cells(1) <> "" Then
        Open destFile For Output As #1 'create csv file
        Do While rw.Cells(1) <> ""
            Print #1, rw.Cells(1) & " " & rw.Cells(2) & " " & rw.Cells(3) & _
                 " " & rw.Cells(4) & " " & rw.Cells(5) & " " & rw.Cells(6)
            Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
        Loop
        Close #1
        Debug.Print "Created output: " & destFile
    Else
        'no content in file?
        MsgBox "File '" & wb.Name & "' has no content", vbExclamation
    End If

    wb.Close False 'don't save

End Sub
```

Comment: i am getting an error on line "Print #2, rw.Cells(1) & " " & rw.Cells(2) & " " & rw.Cells(3) & _
                 " " & rw.Cells(4) & " " & rw.Cells(5) & " " & rw.Cells(6)"

Comment: The message shows: Run-Time Error '52' bad file name or number, i did try using msgbox to ensure the path is correct, yes it's correct as i can msgbox the cell info from my workbook. i am not sure what's going on in here.

Comment: Thanks man, i learnt a lot from this , I did solved my problems as well.

Comment: Sorry that should have been `Print #1` - fixed above